# Make a reusable function to target elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my first time posting a question, so I apologize if it's not formatted correctly. Thanks in advance for any help! 
I want to change the if statement in the event handler to a function that can be reused if the size of the array is more than two elements.

```
    const classList = document.querySelector('.activities');
    const classes = classList.children;

    // arrays for classes at the same time
    const tueMorningClasses = [];
    const tueAfternoonClasses = [];
    const wedMorningClasses = [];
    const wedAfternoonClasses =[];

    // loop to seperate classes into arrays
    for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i += 1) {
        if (classes[i].className === "tue-morning") {
            tueMorningClasses.push(classes[i].firstElementChild);
        } else if (classes[i].className === "tue-afternoon") {
            tueAfternoonClasses.push(classes[i].firstElementChild);
        } else if (classes[i].className === "wed-morning") {
            wedMorningClasses.push(classes[i].firstChildElement);
        } else if (classes[i].className === "wed-afternoon") {
            wedAfternoonClasses.push(classes[i].firstChildElement);
        }
    }

classList.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const box = event.target;
    const boxChecked = box.checked;
    if (tueMorningClasses[0] === box) {
        if (boxChecked) {
            tueMorningClasses[1].disabled = true;
        } else {
            tueMorningClasses[1].disabled = false;
        }
    } else if (tueMorningClasses[1] === box) {
        if (boxChecked) {
            tueMorningClasses[0].disabled = true;
        } else {
            tueMorningClasses[0].disabled = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @usr2564301.

Comment: So... if there are more than two elements, which element would get disabled? The next one (wrapping around)? The previous one? All remaining ones except the selected?

Comment: If there were say 4 elements in the array, I want to disable all but the one that is checked but still be able to uncheck it. I tried a for loop and was able to disable all elements. Not quite what I want to do. Something like for(i=0;i<tueMorningClasses.length;i+=1)if (tueMorningClasses[i] === box) {
        if (boxChecked) {
            tueMorningClasses[i].disabled = true;
        } else {
            tueMorningClasses[i].disabled = false;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It's untested so may contain typos, and there's a gap where I'm not sure how to deduce the class time from the HTML element.

```
const classList = document.querySelector('.activities');
const classes = classList.children;

// arrays for classes at the same time
const classTimes = ['tue-morning', 'tue-afternoon', 'wed-morning', 'wed-afternoon'];
const classesByTime = {};
for (let i in classTimes) {
    classesByTime[classTimes[i]] = [];
}

// loop to separate classes into arrays
for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i += 1) {
    const time = classes[i].className;
    classesByTime[time].push(classes[i].firstElementChild);
}

classList.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const box = event.target;
    const boxChecked = box.checked;
    const time = // TODO: not sure what goes in here - should be 'tue-morning', 'tue-afternoon', etc, depending on `box`.
    for (let i = 0; i < classesByTime[time].length; i++) {
        classesByTime[time][i].disabled = (boxChecked && classesByTime[time][i] !== box);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but using that code I get an error trying to append to an undefined array

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which array is undefined?

Comment: classesByTime[time].push(classes[i].firstElementChild);

Comment: This line throws the error: TypeError: cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: That means `classesByTime[time]` is `undefined`. Which means `time` is not an element of the array `classTimes`. I assumed that `classes[i].className` was always one of the ones on my list, but I haven't seen your HTML so what do I know? If you want it to ignore such elements, as your original code would have done, then replace that line with `if(classesByTime[time]) { classesByTime[time].push(classes[i].firstElementChild); }`.

Comment: Ok, thanks I’ll give it a shot. Let you know how I make out. Thank you for all of your help, much appreciated!

Comment: So it sort of works, it now selects multiple checkboxes that shouldn't be disabled. The time variable is giving me trouble. I can't figure out how to get the class from the checkbox to give time a value.  Here's the HTML related to the javascript

Comment: So the html is posted above your answer. Still have a learning curve with posting on stack, sorry about that

Comment: The class is in the label, not the checkbox inside it. `box` could be either the label or the checkbox, depending on where the user clicked. I'll assume you only want it to work if they clicked the checkbox. In that case it should work with `const time = box.parentElement.className;`. This is ugly, however - if `box` is the label, then `time === 'activities'`. I'd rather set the handler on the label or input, then `const boxLabel = event.currentTarget;`. Also, using the `class` attribute to store time won't work if someone adds another class. You could add attribute `data-time="tue-morning"`.

Comment: Also, this is a very old-school way of doing things. You could have used a framework like Angular, React, etc. But I didn't want to rewrite the whole thing from scratch :-)

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work the way that i wanted. I know this is old school but I'm trying to get a better understanding of JavaScript. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  <fieldset class="activities">
    <legend>Register for Activities</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="all"> Main Conference — $200</label>
    <label class="tue-morning"><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks"> JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
    <label class="tue-afternoon"><input type="checkbox" name="js-libs"> JavaScript Libraries Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
    <label class="tue-morning"><input type="checkbox" name="express"> Express Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
    <label class="tue-afternoon"><input type="checkbox" name="node"> Node.js Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>          
    <label class="wed-morning"><input type="checkbox" name="build-tools"> Build tools Workshop — Wednesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
    <label class="wed-afternoon"><input type="checkbox" name="npm"> npm Workshop — Wednesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>

  </fieldset>
```